# How do I create a static library in Rust to link with C code in Windows?

Tags: c, windows, gcc, rust

I have 2 files:

**func.rs**

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn double_input(input: i32) -> i32 { input * 2 }
```

**main.c**

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern int32_t double_input(int32_t input);

int main() {
   int input = 4;
   int output = double_input(input);
   printf("%d * 2 = %d\n", input, output);
   return 0;
}
```

I want to create static lib in Rust and link the library to main.c. My active toolchain is `stable-i686-pc-windows-gnu`. I'm doing this in cmd:

```
rustc --crate-type=staticlib func.rs
```

But the file **func.lib** is created, so I do:

```
gcc -o myprog main.c func.lib -lgcc_eh -lshell32 -luserenv -lws2_32 -ladvapi32
```

But I get an error:

```
undefined reference to __ms_vsnprintf'
```

If I do:

```
rustc --crate-type=staticlib --target=i686-unknown-linux-gnu lib.rs
```

Then **libfunc.a** is created, but when I do:

```
gcc -o myprog main.c libfunc.a
```

I get an error:

```
main.c:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `double_input'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `gcc -o myprog main.c libfunc.a` ---> `gcc -lfunc.a  main.c -o myprog`

Comment: What happens if you use `gcc -o myprog main.c func.lib`? You are doing all of this on Windows, right - how come you don't put a .exe extension on the executable?

Comment: @immibis `--target=i686-unknown-linux-gnu` I don't think it's on windows.

Comment: Well then "My active toolchain: stable-i686-pc-windows-gnu" - why are you using a Windows toolchain on Linux? Are you trying to cross-compile?

Comment: @immibis I tried using i686-unknown-linux-gnu in Linux.
If I use: `gcc -o myprog main.c func.lib`, then I do:
`gcc -o myprog main.c func.lib -lgcc_eh -lshell32 -luserenv -lws2_32 -ladvapi32`
But I get an error:
`undefined reference to __ms_vsnprintf'`

Comment: Try using `gcc -o myprog main.c -L </path/to/libfunc.a> -lfunc`

Comment: Does Rust know that C expects all functions to start with an underscore? i.e. what if you call the Rust function `_double_input(...)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

TL;DR: Install a different flavor of GCC

```
pacman -R local/gcc
pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-gcc
```

---

Half-informed guessing follows...

After some help on Rust IRC, it sounds like the issue is that the MSYS2 / MinGW `gcc` is a "stock" compiler, one without special knowledge of MSYS / MinGW / Windows special features.

`mingw-w64-i686-gcc` (or `mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc`) *does* know about Windows-specific symbols, which libbacktrace, a part of the Rust distribution, requires.

The "correct" GCC build should have the string "Built by MSYS2 project" in the `gcc --version` output.

---

With that, the full process looks like:

```
$ rustc --version --verbose
rustc 1.17.0 (56124baa9 2017-04-24)
host: i686-pc-windows-gnu
$ gcc --version
gcc.exe (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 6.3.0

$ rustc --crate-type=staticlib func.rs
note: link against the following native artifacts when linking against this static library
note: the order and any duplication can be significant on some platforms, and so may need to be preserved
note: library: advapi32
note: library: ws2_32
note: library: userenv
note: library: shell32
note: library: gcc_eh
$ gcc -o main main.c func.lib -ladvapi32 -lws2_32 -luserenv -lshell32 -lgcc_eh
$ ./main
4 * 2 = 8
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! I can not believe it!:)

Answer (score -1):

sorry for my bad english, to use a static rust library (.lib) you must add the following libraries to your linker:

- shell32.lib advapi32.lib cfgmgr32.lib comctl32.lib comdlg32.lib
  d2d1.lib dwrite.lib dxgi.lib gdi32.lib kernel32.lib msimg32.lib
  ole32.lib opengl32.lib shlwapi.lib user32.lib windowscodecs.lib
  winspool.lib userenv.lib ws2_32.lib bcrypt.lib msvcrt.lib
  oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib

works in visual studio 2022