# Interaction between Julia and Rust

Tags: rust, julia

Is there any way to interact between Julia and Rust, a way that allow:

1. Calling/Executing Rust function from Julia
2. Calling/Executing Julia from Rust

Thanks

Comment: check this https://github.com/alexcrichton/rust-ffi-examples/tree/a2ddf21e4/julia-to-rust

Comment: This question is beautiful per se

Comment: Thanks @ozkriff, what about the opposite way, i.e. calling Julia from Rust?

Comment: @ozkriff, I think you expand that into an answer!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Calling Rust function from Julia, like ccall

There's an example for this in [alexcrichton/rust-ffi-examples](https://github.com/alexcrichton/rust-ffi-examples/tree/a2ddf21e4/julia-to-rust) repo:

`Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "julia-to-rust"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["timmonfette1 <monfette.timothy@gmail.com>"]

[lib]
name = "double_input"
crate-type = ["dylib"]
```

`src/lib.rs`:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn double_input(input: i32) -> i32 {
    input * 2
}
```

`src/main.jl`:

```
input = Int32(10)
output =  ccall((:double_input, "target/debug/libdouble_input"),
                        Int32, (Int32,), input)

print(input)
print(" * 2 = ")
println(output)
```

`Makefile`:

```
ifeq ($(shell uname),Darwin)
    EXT := dylib
else
    EXT := so
endif

all: target/debug/libdouble_input.$(EXT)
    julia src/main.jl

target/debug/libdouble_input.$(EXT): src/lib.rs Cargo.toml
    cargo build

clean:
    rm -rf target
```

The idea is that you export a non-mangled function and compile your rust library to a normal native shared library. Then you just use standard C FFI of Julia.

> Calling Julia from Rust

I guess it's better to use [`julia` crate](https://crates.io/crates/julia) for this - it provides a safe wrapper over a [raw C API](https://github.com/pi-pi3/julia-rs/tree/master/julia-sys). Example from the repo:

```
fn main() {
    use julia::api::{Julia, Value};

    let mut jl = Julia::new().unwrap();
    jl.eval_string("println(\"Hello, Julia!\")").unwrap();
    // Hello, Julia!

    let sqrt = jl.base().function("sqrt").unwrap();

    let boxed_x = Value::from(1337.0);
    let boxed_sqrt_x = sqrt.call1(&boxed_x).unwrap();

    let sqrt_x = f64::try_from(boxed_sqrt_x).unwrap();
    println!("{}", sqrt_x);
    // 36.565010597564445
}
```

Comment: How can I make output file like `run.o` instead of the make file?

Comment: @HasanAYousef how to compile rust code to a static library?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43866969 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50229088 should help

Comment: You don't *have to* use the julia crate. You can always run bindgen yourself. But you *should* use it, because it is easier.

Answer (score 3):

#### Executing Julia from Rust

Use Rust's [`Command`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html).

Create a `main.jl` file that contains:

```
# __precompile__()   # If required to be kept precompiled for faster execution
# name = isempty(ARGS) ? "name" : ARGS[1] # To check input arguments
println("hello from Julia function")
```

Create a `main.rs` file that contains:

```
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello from Rust");
    let mut cmd = Command::new("Julia");
    cmd.arg("main.jl");
    // cmd.args(&["main.jl", "arg1", "arg2"]);
    match cmd.output() {
        Ok(o) => unsafe {
            println!("Output: {}", String::from_utf8_unchecked(o.stdout));
        },
        Err(e) => {
            println!("There was an error {}", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, by running `cargo run` you'll get the required output below:

[image]

#### Executing Rust from Julia

Use the [calling-c-and-fortran-code](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v0.6.1/manual/calling-c-and-fortran-code/) by [ccall](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v0.6.1/stdlib/c/#ccall)

Create a Rust shared library using a `lib.rs` file that contains:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn double_input(input: i32) -> i32 {
    println!("Hello from Rust");
    input * 2
}
```

The `Cargo.toml` for building the library:

```
[package]
name = "julia_call_rust"
version = "1.0.0"
authors = ["hasan yousef]

[lib]
name = "my_rust_lib"
crate-type = ["dylib"]
```

Create a `main.jl` file, that contains:

```
println("Hello from Julia")
input = 10 #Int32(10)
output =  ccall(   #(:function or "function", "library"), Return type, (Input types,), arguments if any)
                (:double_input,
                "target/debug/libmy_rust_lib"),
                Int32,          # Return type
                (Int32,),       # (Input types,)
                input)          # Arguments if any
println("As result of $input * 2 is: $output")
```

Run `cargo build` to get the Rust library built, and run `julia main.jl` to get the required output below:

[image]